# Capture generic type in Java

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

If I have something like:

```
class Test<T extends X> {
    public T test() {
        T t = /* ... */;
        return t;
    }
}
```

How can I capture `T`'s class so I can instantiate it? Are there workarounds to prevent type erasure? I don't even need to have access to `T`'s methods, `X`'s will do just fine, but I need to return a `T`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you can do is to pass the class of T as an extra argument, either to `test()` or set a member field in class `Test`. You can't prevent type erasure.

```
class Test<T extends X> {
    private Class<T> mClass;
    public Test(Class<T> c) {
        mClass = c;
    }
    public T test() {
        T t = mClass.newInstance();
        return t;
    }
}
```

Or you can pass a factory object to the same effect. This works well when you need to use something other than a default constructor.

Comment: mClass.getConstructor().newInstance() is better as it doesn't hide checked exceptions but properly wraps them in InvocationTargetException.

Answer (score 3):

Define it as:

```
class Test<T extends X>
{
    public T test(Class<T> c)
    {
        T t = c.newInstance();
        return t;
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
Test<Foo> t = new Test<Foo>();
t.test(Foo.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly, but you can add an interface that T implements to create an instance, or an array of T.